# Assign outcome from SQL query to column

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a dataframe (test_df) that looks like this:

```
dq_code      dq_sql                                             Results
ID_24        select 'A' as B,  'B' as C, ...
ID_42        select * from dual
```

I want to assign the result from executing the query in dq_sql to the column Results. I tried this:

```
test_df['Results'] = '' 
for row in test_df.itertuples():
    test_df['Results'] = pd.read_sql(row.dq_sql, engine)
```

which results in:

```
     dq_code           dq_sql                                     Results
0    ID_24             select 'A' as B,  'B' as C, ...              X
1    ID_42             select * from dual                           NaN
```

Strange thing is, the 'X' result should be assigned to row 1, whereas the query in row 0 does not seem to run. When I try to run the query in row 0 without the for loop, like this:

```
query = 
     '''
     select
    'A' as B, 
    'B' as C,
    'C' as D,
    'E/'||to_char(Key_1,'YYYYMMDD') as Key,
    sysdate as Date1,
    sysdate as Date2,
    'The date' as Reason,
    'The date was ' || to_char(Key_1,'YYYYMMDD') as Wrong_val, 
    'Test' as Case, 
    Null as Value,
    Null as Info_1,
    Null as Info_2,
    Null as Info_3
    from schema.table TAB
    where Key_1 between sysdate-7 AND sysdate
    '''
    
    query_test = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

It does give me the results I need. But somehow it does not when I include this query in the for-loop.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it worked out by (1) creating an empty dataframe which contains a column, (2) appending the results from the query to that column. Used a dictionary to do so, and removed the index twice in order to remove redundant brackets. Not necessarily using any form of itertuples, iterrows or else.

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Results'])

for query in test_df['dq_sql']:
    df = df.append({'Results': pd.read_sql_query(str(query),conn).values[0][0]}, ignore_index=True)
```